# How to implement a payment on a web page using MyEtherWallet?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapp-development, myetherwallet

I have seen a few solutions regarding implementing a payment (like donating) on a web page using MetaMask.

But I really want to know if we can do that same payment on a web page with MyEtherWallet too. I have been trying to find solution to do with the MyEtherWallet, and I have not found one yet.

Any solutions or ideas, I highly appreciate. Thank you.